# Idiom for frustrating someone else's plans by taking what the other person wanted in the first place

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, spanish

There's an idiom in Argentina translated roughly as "to sleep someone" *(dormir a alguien*), which is used when someone frustrates the plans of someone else by taking what the other person wanted in the first place and who obtains the benefit knows it. This may cover different situations, for example:

- If you walk ahead in the street to hail the taxi another person was about to hail.
- If you start dating someone another person you know was eager to ask for a date and you knew it.
- If you take the last slice of a pizza someone who went for a drink said was going to take.

I'm looking for an idiom in English which describes this kind of behavior or situations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there figurative or idiomatic English expressions to mean hindering a person in achieving work / attempt?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204875/are-there-figurative-or-idiomatic-english-expressions-to-mean-hindering-a-person)

Comment: They may be somewhat similar, but I don't think that's close enough to be a dupe. None of the offered answers would fit this question. Those are all intentional reductions, this is what Alanis Morrisette would confuse with irony ;)

Comment: The closer two languages, the more likely that equivalent expressions in one language will be borrowed by the other, as 'Vive la difference' or 'mot juste' in English.  It enriches our language world.  Argentinian Spanish hasn't the proximity to English that French once had, when enough English people knew French and were attracted by and 'borrowed' such phrases. The Argentinian phrase is delightful, but the language, I fear, too distant to catch on.  Sadly, we have no true equivalent.

Comment: Incidentally, the African American English (I believe that is its origin) phrase "he slept him" means that the subject knocked the object out (often in one punch).

Comment: If you look closely to the three examples given, you'll see a common component of passiveness in the person who lost the object of his/her desire: lost the taxi because stoodstill waiting for the car to pass by while someone else walked ahead; who lost the date maybe waited to much to make the invitation, and who wanted the last slice of pizza went for a drink instead of eat it right away. So, in line with the spirit of the original idiom, I think the emphasis of the related idiom shouldn't be on the behavior of who took the benefits but on the passivity of the other person.

Comment: In French we have "to cut the herb under someone's foot". And if you were about to say something but I say it before you, then I "took the words out of your mouth".

Comment: @Sebafff "Emphasis of the related idiom shouldn't be on the behavior of who took the benefits but on the passivity of the other person" -- Combining that with the idea of "sleeping" from your original expression, that would suggest the common idiom (in English): **You snooze, you lose.**

Comment: Is it being done specifically out of spite? I.e. in your examples, the person's goal was to frustrate the other person; their goal was not just wanting a taxi or also genuinely wanting to date this third person?

Comment: [correction: who wanted the last slice of pizza went for a drink instead of **eating** it right away.  AND If you take the last slice of a pizza from someone who went for a drink and said they were going to take it. [?]

Comment: Back when hunting wild animals with dogs was legal in England, one phase was "you've shot my fox" as suggesting you undermined my plans in a rather unsporting manner.

Comment: I suggest however closely you look, there is no more element of 'passiveness' than of ignorance and the protagonist’s actions can't change that.

'… taking what the other person wanted in the first place' is so unclear, it's unlikely '… in the first place' comes into this.

This might sound pedantic yet whether 'in the first place' meant simply '… what the other wanted' or '… pre-emptively taking what the other wanted' still, ’in the first place' has no useful place here.

Comment: In gaming that would be a [*kill steal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_stealing).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the closest idiom is ***beat someone to the punch***. The idiom is originated from boxing, where it literally means a boxer lands a punch before their opponent could. Another version is *beat someone to the draw*. I think it has a similar metaphoric connection with the Spanish idiom *dormir a alguien* 'put/send someone to sleep' (which could also mean *knock someone out*).

[*MW*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beat%20%28someone%29%20to%20the%20punch) definition:

> to do or achieve something before someone else is able to

[*OED*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/beat_v1?tab=meaning_and_use#25430732) definition in extended use:

> to anticipate or forestall a person's speech or action.

Comment: I agree with you; beat someone to the punch has a similar meaning and goes in line with the spirit of the original idiom. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sebafff I'm not so sure - to beat someone to the punch has a very positive connotation - congratulations, you beat him to the punch. The examples you gave were all very mean-spirited.

Comment: @IanGoldby it is neutral in my opinion. No issue with using it for something rude.

Comment: @Casey I would say that for the OP's examples you'd want sometime with a clear negative connotation, so even neutral could give the wrong impression. As always, it's subjective. But usually one would want to choose words that are unlikely to be misinterpreted.

Comment: @IanGoldby The literal meaning of this phrase which is being used for a metaphor is outright striking someone.  I think it is perfect.  [Here is a news story](https://www.wxyz.com/news/richard-wershe-arrested-in-miami-on-robbery-and-battery-charges):  "This individual robbed him. When he told her bring back my watch, she refused. When he told her bring back my watch or I’m going to the police, she beat him to the punch and filed a fake report that he punched her."

Comment: @IanGoldby if your position is that most people would see filing a false police report as appropriate or “sporting” then I think we just do not see the world in similar terms.

Comment: While it may sometimes be used the other way, at least to me, "beat to the punch" does carry a connotation that it was a fair contest -- or at least it doesn't imply cheating. The OP's examples all do include an aspect of unfairness or dishonesty, so it feels like this idiom doesn't quite fit.

Answer (score 14):

[**steal someone's thunder**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steal-thunder) means to do what someone else was going to do before they do it, especially if this takes success or praise away from them.

Examples:

> You have a significant part to play in your own career success, so
> don't let anyone else steal your thunder.
>
> I had put in a lot of effort to produce a perfect analysis, but in the
> end, a colleague of mine stole my thunder.

[Origin](https://www.theidioms.com/steal-thunder/):

> The origin of this phrase is attributed to an English playwright John
> Dennis. In 1704, he had invented a new method of creating the sound of
> thunder and used it in his play “Appius and Virginia”. The play was
> unsuccessful. Shortly afterwards, the thunder method was used in a
> performance of Macbeth. Dennis was not pleased and said “Damn them!
> They will not let my play run, but they steal my thunder.”

Comment: The difference here is that _your_ thunder has always been yours, and the person stealing it has stolen directly from you.  OP wants an expression for when you take something 'free' that was pledged or owed to someone else - it _should_ have been theirs, but you ignored social convention and got to it first.

Comment: @Kirt: This is not wrong. If the "battle" was not too unfair, you may say *I was pipped at the post* in case of defeat.

Comment: @Kirt: I could continue your rebuttal with a philosophy on you owning thunder. Instead, it's more productive to consider that you might not get an atomically perfect translation. The question is whether the spirit is preserved. Stealing someone's thunder is done specifically to disadvantage the person - as opposed to simply competing with the person for the resource. If I take the last slice of pizza just because I want to deny you from having it, I'm stealing your thunder. If I did it because I was hungry, that's different. If OP's saying implies doing it spitefully, it's a correct answer.

Comment: @Flater It is certainly possible that there is no perfect translation.  In that case an answer is not correct merely because it is close, but because it is the closest among those suggested.

Comment: @Kirt: The point is more that not every facet (nor every possible way to stress something) is therefore a _necessary_ one.

Comment: @Flater I don't think I ever said that a correct answer had to have every facet necessary.  I just pointed out _one_ facet in which this answer was different from what OP sought.  It is then OP's prerogative to find among the answers the one that fits their meaning best.

Comment: I guess this technically fits for the OP's phrasing of the question, but it doesn't work for any of OP's examples.

Comment: I also just realized that Steal your thunder doesn't actually apply to the situation at all. Stealing one's thunder is about outshining someone one who was expected to shine and has nothing to do with being first. If a celeb proposes at a normal person's wedding, they will steal the bride and groom's thunder, despite being the second event (after/during the first event--the wedding)

Answer (score 10):

The metaphorical broadening of 'cut in on' has the meaning 'take another's [rightful / better deserved / established] place':

> **cut in** [intransitive verb] [*often* on someone]
>
> 1: to thrust oneself into a position between others or belonging to
> another

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut%20in)]

Examples appearing on the internet:

> - *a group of white businessmen decided to cut in on the profits* [[Hackney Music Development
>   Trust](http://www.hmdt.org.uk/Assets/Shadowball/FINAL%20SHADOWBALL%20TEACHING%20PACK%20vRW1.pdf)]
> - *Chinese automakers cut in on Japanese rivals in Indonesia.* [[Financial
>   Times](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cut+in+on%22&sca_esv=562184719&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=tTvzZLH7FY6ahbIPwcmjiA8&ved=0ahUKEwjxqdCOh4yBAxUOTUEAHcHkCPEQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22cut+in+on%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiCyJjdXQgaW4gb24iMgUQABiABDIGEAAYBxgeMggQABiKBRiRAjIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMggQABgIGAcYHjIIEAAYCBgHGB4yCBAAGAgYBxgeMggQABgIGAcYHjIIEAAYCBgHGB5I_QhQtgZYtgZwAXgBkAEAmAFUoAFUqgEBMbgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPiAwQYACBBiAYBkAYI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1)]
> - *Prosecutors allege co-defendant Wes Doughty killed the couple shortly after they moved in because he thought Greenlaw was going to
>   cut in on his drug business.* [[NBC
>   Boston](https://www.nbcboston.com/news/local/accessory-after-the-fact-guilty-plea-peabody-massachusetts-double-homicide/30332/)]

The term is often used in dancing circles, for instance

> - *Emily Post dictated that cutting was an almost universal practice, so if someone cut in on a man, for the time being he just had to live
>   with it.... Men were allowed to 'rescue' their dates by cutting back
>   in if ....*

[['Great Depression and the Middle Class: Experts, Collegiate Youth and ...'By Mary C. McComb](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nRDaAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=%22cut+in+on%22&source=bl&ots=VcfYnZLAI5&sig=ACfU3U303WaFLmO3PTJnPgZ_tBjE70dy1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK1uTch4yBAxVqTEEAHbgOBC44PBDoAXoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=%22cut%20in%20on%22&f=false)]

Where the infringement is serious, 'muscle in on' is an informal alternative:

> **muscle in [on]** [phrasal verb with muscle as simplex verb] [informal]
>
> to force your way into a situation and make certain you are included,
> although you are not wanted

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/muscle-in)]

> - *Cohen complained that Kravis was muscling in on his deal* [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/muscle-in)]

Comment: Similar to 'cut in', and perhaps more idiomatic would be [horn in](https://grammarist.com/idiom/home-in-vs-horn-in/#:~:text=Horn%20in%20means%20to%20intrude,forward%20by%20using%20its%20horns.)

Answer (score 7):

The question as asked:
..."which is used when someone frustrates the plans of someone else by taking what the other person wanted in the first place and who obtains the benefit knows it"

To **thwart** someone's plans.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/thwart)
to stop something from happening or someone from doing something:
Our vacation plans were thwarted by the airline pilots' strike
Synonyms

Comment: But the striking pilots didn't take the vacation we had planned.  OP's use is not just that their plans were thwarted, but that the person thwarting them then enjoyed the benefit.

Comment: @Kirt Presumably if you thwart something, it is to get a benefit from it, unless you are just being mean, which itself can be a benefit to you.

Comment: You could be a 'griefer', but more likely you are opposing the other person's plans because you oppose them in general.  The benefit you derive is that they are losing - their loss is your gain in a zero-sum competition.  But OP's use is that the interloper is specifically gaining what their opponent loses.  Yes, it is thwarting, but I think it is more specific than that.

Comment: @Kirt It may be more specific but I don't see a single word doing the job, like so many questions around here.

Comment: Some things just don't have exact translations...

Answer (score 7):

Colloquially, to get **scooped** by someone means that someone else has beaten you to a particular achievement or accomplishment, typically in a competitive or time-sensitive context. This term is often used in journalism, research, and various fields where being the first to report or discover something is important.

For example:

- In journalism: If one news outlet publishes a breaking news story before another, the second outlet might say they got "scooped" by the first, indicating that they missed the opportunity to report the news first.
- In scientific research: If one group of researchers publishes a groundbreaking discovery before another group, the second group might feel they got "scooped" because they were working on a similar project but were not the first to publish their findings.
- In business: If one company launches a new product or service before another with similar plans, the second company might feel they got "scooped" in the market, potentially affecting their success.

In essence, getting "scooped" means losing out on the chance to be the first to achieve or report something, often resulting in missed opportunities or a diminished impact compared to the competitor who acted first.

I think it's applicable to all your examples:

- *I ran ahead and scooped their taxi.*
- *Someone in my class scooped my date for the prom.*
- *When they went for a drink, I scooped the last slice of pizza.*

In the dictionary, you typically only see the usage as it pertains to journalism.  But I think it applies well colloquially in these other contexts, but it sounds quite informal.

Comment: I thought of 'scooped' as well, and it is certainly understandable in the context.  However, I think 'scooped' usually connotes someone got to something first that you wanted, but not that was somehow _owed_ to you.  A news story doesn't 'belong' to anyone, whereas a taxi 'should' go to the person who was first in line.

Answer (score 7):

This may not be the best answer out of the ones that have already been provided, but given the context of sleeping in your original translation, I'd like to offer:

### You snooze, you lose

[link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-snooze-you-lose)

This is said by the person who frustrates the other, as a justification for why they were entitled to take the [resource] that they know the other person also wanted.

A more verbose meaning would be "if you sleep, be too late and lose out on [it] because someone else now had the chance to take it".

Answer (score 6):

### Gazump

> make a higher offer for a house than (someone whose offer has already been accepted by the seller) and thus succeed in acquiring the property.
>
> "the trio are fuming after they were gazumped by a property speculator"

The formal usage is as above but it also has a metaphorical usage of taking an opportunity that rightfully belongs to someone else.

### [Cutting someone’s grass](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cutting%20someone%27s%20grass)

> Getting/flirting with someone who your friend has already gotten with or 'shotgunned'.

Also, cut another’s lunch.

Specifically related to dating/sex.

Comment: Gazumping is entirely legal in England and Wales. However, this word is very specific to property law and other purchases.

Comment: @pjc50 Also legal in the US - real estate transactions typically aren't binding until the closing of a written contract.

Comment: What's the source of the first quote?

Answer (score 5):

The closest idiom I can think of is "to steal a march" on someone. From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steal-a-march-on):

> If you steal a march on someone, you get an advantage over that person by acting before they do:
>
> - *Our rival company managed to steal a march on us by bringing out their software ahead of ours.*

Answer (score 5):

**pre-empt** [or **preempt**] *v* *trans.*

4. to forestall or prevent (something anticipated) by acting first; preclude; head off:
   *an effort to preempt inflation.*

Comment: What's the source of this definition?

Answer (score 2):

### The early bird catches the worm

> a saying that means someone will have an advantage if they do something immediately, or **before other people do it**: ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/early-bird-catches-the-worm))

The following is the translation of the Italian proverb “l’occasione fa l’uomo ladro". In its metaphorical sense, the expression claims a person will take illicit advantage if the opportunity arises.

### opportunity makes the thief

Comment: But the second mouse gets the cheese ;-).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect match, and depends as much on the other person/people being offended as it does on the action itself, but several of the examples in the question suggested the phrase "to tread on someone's toes".

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tread-on-someones-toes) has "to offend or insult someone, esp by infringing on his or her sphere of action, etc ". [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tread%20on%20%28someone%27s%29%20toes) keeps it as vague as possible with "to do something that upsets or offends (someone)", but the implication is you've gone into their space and caused them annoyance or discomfort.

It might also be unintentional / inadvertent, and people might be trying to avoid doing it. [thefreedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tread+on+toes) has an example "Now that we have proper job descriptions we are less likely to tread on each other’s toes."

Answer (score 2):

### They are a claim-jumper

In a literal sense, a "claim" is a legal right to extract mineral resources from a parcel of land.  A [claim-jumper](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/claim-jumper) is someone who tries to control the land another person has a legal claim to, or who works the land without attempting to control it.

In an idiomatic or metaphorical sense, a claim-jumper is someone who takes something that someone else has claimed; either the claimant or social convention has established them as the *future* owner, but the jumper moves in first and obtains the good or benefit knowing that they are violating norms.

This use of "claimed" can be seen in *The Walking Dead* episodes "Claimed" and "Us".

A century ago, such a person might have been called a "[sooner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sooner#:%7E:text=%3A%20a%20person%20settling%20on%20land,sooner)":

> a person settling on land in the early West before its official opening to settlement in order to gain the prior claim allowed by law to the first settler after official opening

However, this has since fallen out of general idiomatic use and now mostly refers to a specific historical context

In the specific example of:

> If you start dating someone another person you know was eager to ask for a date and you knew it.

This is a violation of the "dibs" rule in the [bro code](https://www.quora.com/Me-and-my-friend-like-the-same-girl-How-does-the-bro-rule-affect-us#:%7E:text=Two%20Bro%20Rules%20come%20into,the%20girl%20has%20to%20go.), although I don't know a specific idiomatic expression for someone who violates the bro code.

Comment: I disagree about this answer, because a claim-jumper specifically ignores a rightful claim. In OP's case, the contested resource had not yet been assigned to the other person. My issue isn't in the minute difference between the two definitions, but rather than "claim-jumper" very intently focuses on a part that is explicitly mentioned to be absent in OP's case.

Comment: @Flater As my answer explains, this is not claim-jumping in a literal sense because they have not established a _de jure_ claim to what you are taking.  However, it is an idiomatic or metaphorical claim, because the force of social convention has assigned them the good.  In each of OP's three examples, you know that the good _should_ go to them by rights.

Answer (score 2):

**Pipped at the post** would be my pick. Collins Dictionary defines it as follows:

> PHRASE
> If someone is pipped at the post or pipped to the post they are just beaten in a competition or in a race to achieve something.
> [British, informal]
> I didn't want us to be pipped to the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you and someone else both want the same thing, and you take it, depriving the other person of it as a side-effect, then ermanen's suggestion of "beat them to the punch" is probably best.

However, there is a particular idiom for the related scenario where you don't particularly want the thing, and your main motivation is to deprive the other person: in that case you are being "a dog in the manger". This comes from a [Greek fable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_in_the_Manger) (sometimes attributed, probably incorrectly, to Aesop).

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to **stymie** (which can be either a noun or verb).  Unlike the others, it refers to blocking another person from progressing by getting *closer* than them to the goal, without having achieved it yet.  Merriam-Webster [gives the following explanation:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stymie)

> Golf was being played in Scotland as early as the 15th century, but it wasn't until the 19th century that the sport really caught on in England and North America. It was also in the 19th century that the word stymie entered English as a noun referring to a golfing situation in which one player's ball lies between another ball and the hole on the putting green, thereby blocking the line of play. Later, stymie came to be used as a verb meaning "to bring into the position of, or impede by, a stymie." By the early 20th century, the verb was being applied in similarly vexing non-golf contexts.

Modern golf no longer allows this: the first player would today remove the ball and place a marker, such as a coin, so as to remove the obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "throw someone under the bus"?

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Throw+under+the+bus) gives:

> throw (one) under the bus
>
> 1. To exploit one's trust for an ulterior purpose, advantage, or agenda; to harm one through deceit or treachery.
>
> *Senator Davis was
> supposed to be working with me to bridge the gap between Democrats and
> Republicans on the issue of gun control, but, instead, she threw me
> under the bus to get a boost in the polls with her constituency.*
>
> *The
> investment company threw its clients under the bus when it chose to
> redirect their hard earned money into various Ponzi schemes that
> benefited only a few board members at the top.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your second example, "If you start dating someone another person you know was eager to ask for a date and you knew it", which does pair better with the term "stole their thunder", I'm genuinely surprised no one has just suggested the word "foiled".  It seems the most applicable to the other two situations. You "foiled their plans".

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment:

> I think the emphasis of the related idiom shouldn't be on the behavior of who took the benefits but on the **passivity of the other person**.

This would describe what happened to them:

> Fell asleep at the wheel
>
> [informal: not attentive or alert; inactive.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/asleep+at+the+wheel)

But this would describe the action which led them there:

> Reveal (one's) hand
>
> [To make one's plans, intentions, ideas, or resources known to others, especially those that were previously hidden or kept secret.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/reveal+your+hand)

Answer (score -1):

The early bird gets the worm, is something the doer of the transgression would likely call out so maybe the is room for creating an idiom to fill the void.

Comment: This could be used in certain instances, but is not necessarily the same as the idiom the OP is requesting.